# How to Improve Performance for Query?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table a and b with columns as below:

```
Table A
a.code_1    varchar(10)
Table B
b.code_1    varchar(30)
Reference join A and B is A.code_1 = B.Code_1
```

So, I have to use

```
CONVERT(a.code_1,CHAR(10)) = CONVERT(b.code_1,CHAR(10))
```

at where conditions.

=> It's so much slow. How can I improve performance. I don't have permission to change tables structure.

Comment: You get the best performance if both have the same type and you don't need to convert

Comment: Should you have to convert work on where condition? Looks that is unneccesary

Comment: If I don't convert on where condition, I'll get Error with code is 1267